# HttpPost Data in JSV formst

Tags: servicestack

I need to communicate with a service stack web service. It appears to accept form content with jsv values.

Is there a way to serialize an object In such a way that this happens automatically?  Something like a “JsvFormContent” or such?

Thanks so much!  I’m completely new to service stack.

Comment: Could you visit this page?
https://docs.servicestack.net/jsv-format

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack accepts content in a [number of different formats](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-servicestack#multiple-pluggable-formats), JSV is just one of them, although it's what ServiceStack uses to serialize [complex types QueryString or FormData params](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string), however if you're just sending HTML Form values, they're not complex values so you can send them using the standard HTML Content Types, e.g. (queryString, application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data). If you need to call ServiceStack APIs from any of the [popular supported languages](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) you can just their generic JSON Service Client and generated DTOs.

You should never need to, but if you want to send JSV from C#/.NET you can use the [JsvServiceClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#httpwebrequest-service-clients).

The only time you'll ever need to send JSV is if you need to send complex JS Objects from a browser, in which case you can use the [JSV impl in @servicestack/client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/blob/fdf1c0fec1b6b856f9d5db02a6dea7f3e7f41325/src/index.ts#L2629-L2700) to serialize a JS object to JSV, e.g:

```js
let jsv = JSV.stringify(obj);
```

If you're using any of the SPA project templates `@servicestack/client` is already imported.

Otherwise `@servicestack/client` is [embedded inside ServiceStack.dll](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-client-umd) which you can access with:

```xml
<script src="/js/servicestack-client.js"></script>
```

For older or non ServiceStack apps you can resolve it from [unpkg CDN](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-client-umd#cdn-unpkg) instead:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@servicestack/client/dist/servicestack-client.min.js"></script>
```

Which you can [import into the global namespace](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/web/blob/3cc9901cd8b9c9206f39a504f099951569b4779b/MyApp/wwwroot/index.html#L19-L26) with:

```html
<script>
    var exports = { __esModule:true }, module = { exports:exports }
    function require(name) { return exports[name] || window[name] }
</script>
<script src="/js/servicestack-client.js"></script>
<script>
    Object.assign(window, exports); //import
    let jsv = JSV.stringify(obj);
</script>
```

Comment: When my browser posts the data, it send the following form-encoded data:
https://prnt.sc/1u7kzsr

And this data exactly models values coming out of the API via GET requests.

Is there a built-in way in Service Stack for it to do the conversion from an object into this format?  Or are you saying there is a way that I can post data in JSON and not need to worry about JSV at all?

Comment: @TonyValenti The `*List` properties are complex type values which would need to be serialized as JSV as per my answer.